# Install 1-Wire drivers in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, drivers

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and need to install 1-Wire drivers for an iButton adapter (`DS9490B#`). I installed OneWireViewer and it doesn't recognize the adapter. I found a solution that is installing the drivers but they are only available in windows. Then I installed a Windows 10 Virtual Box and tried to install the drivers there but still, nothing shows in File explorer or Settings > USB in the virtual box. So coming back to the point I need to find how to install those drivers for it to recognize the adapter. Is there any way to install it? Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I would not use the kernel drivers. Instead download, build and use `owfs`.

Comment: Will that make the host recognize the memory?

Comment: Hopefully......

Comment: I just installed the `owfs` driver and I checked it by running the `owfs --v` command and it shows normally. Now what?

Comment: I tested it again and it is still not recognizing anything. What shall I do?

Comment: Make sure you have not loaded the `wire` kernel module, you may have to blacklist it. Then run `owserver` with the correct switches, mine are `--w1 --foreground -uall -p :::4304`, then use ``owdir` which should at least produce some info. If it does not list some device serial numbers, then perhaps it's broken.

Comment: Additional, since you gave no info, within vm, did allow it to be connected via the `devices` menu option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142567/discussion-between-someonethatcodes-and-bib).